# Laravel with pusher, different channels for production and development

Tags: laravel, pusher

I'm using laravel with pusher and after uploading my project to production I've notice that it doesn't matter if I change the keys inside `.env` file, it was still poiting to the development channel instead of production

I don't run `npm run prod` in my server, I run it locally, and locally I have my development keys inside .env, so every time I run `npm run prod` I have to change that keys before sending the compiled files to production

## Is there a way where I can work with two channels in my two enviroments?

my .env file (it is not on source controlled by git, I have differents .env files in my development server and production, I just have to change it local to recompile)

```
PUSHER_APP_ID=******
PUSHER_APP_KEY=****************
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=****************
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=us2

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

`bootstrap.js`

```
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
    encrypted: true,
    disableStats: true,
});
```

What I have to do if I merge my develop branch to my master branch

- Change keys inside .env file
- Recompile with `npm run prod` or `npm run dev`
- Push files with git

What I want to do insted

- Push files with git

Comment: .env should not be source controlled by git, and your assets should be built as part of your deployment pipeline. You surely don't have node_modules source controlled too, do you?

Comment: @KurtFriars It is not, I have to change keys just for compiling

Comment: You should never have to change keys. Your local environment has a .env, and your production environment should have its own .env. When you deploy your code to production, one of the steps should be ```npm run prod```, which uses the production .env values.

Comment: @KurtFriars agree, but i dont run `npm run prod` in my server, I run it locally, and locally I have my development keys inside .env so every time I run `npm run prod` I have to change that keys before sending the compiled files to production